# ClientSideValidations.formBuilders[settings.type] is undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, formtastic, client-side-validation

I'm trying to use client_side_validations gem, but have some problems.
First, I have in my Gemfile

```
 gem 'client_side_validations', :git => 'https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations.git'
```

and I after bundle install I see

Using client_side_validations (3.2.0.beta.2) from https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations.git (at master)

but I don't see this gem in gem list....This is first problem.
Second, and more important, validations do not work. I have an error in firebug console

```
ClientSideValidations.formBuilders[settings.type] is undefined
```

and no validations happen. I'm using rails 3.2.1, formtastic 2.0.2 and here is my client_side_validations.rb file

```
  # ClientSideValidations Initializer

      # Uncomment the following block if you want each input field to have the validation messages attached.
         # ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
    #   unless html_tag =~ /^<label/
            #     %{<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}<label for="#{instance.send(:tag_id)}" class="message">#{instance.error_message.first}</label></div>}.html_safe
         #   else
        #     %{<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}</div>}.html_safe
       #   end
        # end
```

Any help will be appriciated.....

Comment: Did you complete all the steps to install the gem, or did you only run the bundle command? Also, in your form, did you set :validate => :true? Lastly, are you sure the validator isn't running or are you just not seeing the error message appear when you'd expect them to?

Comment: Actually strike my last question, but answers to the other two will help narrow things down :)

Comment: Yes, I did it everything. I've got the answer at last...Problem was that formtastic 2.0 doesn't have formbuilder or something like this, so for using client_side_validations there is an additional gem client_side_validations-formtastic. And it worked out) Anyway, thanks for your answers)

Comment: Aha, good work! Be sure to add your solution and mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that since Formtastic 2.0 version for correct working client_side_validations gem you need to install client_side_validations-formtastic gem.